# Binary Search refactor

Tags: java

I've received this test last night.

```
` int binaryS(int[] A, int X) {
        int N = A.length;
        if (N == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int l = 0;
        int r = N - 1;
        while (l < r) {
            int m = (l + r) / 2;
            if (A[m] > X) {
                r = m - 1;
            } else {
                l = m;
            }
        }
        if (A[l] == X) {
            return l;
        }
        return -1;
    }`
```

And I have to debugg/refactor the code. **Condition:** "You can modify only three lines".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Refactor to do what? And what have you tried?

Comment: *"And **I** have to debugg/refactor the code"* Did you notice you said "I"? As in ***you*** have to do this. Not us. This is *your* assignment. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ --- Also see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code for Binary Search would be:

```
while (l < r) {
    int m = (l + r) / 2;

    if (A[m] == X) {
        return m;
    }
    if (A[m] > X) {
        r = m - 1;
    } 
    else if (A[m] < X) {
        l = m + 1;
    }
}
return -1;
```

Just place the 'found' condition before any other condition in the loop, and you're good to go!